# SQL Performance while setting a Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a SQL Server database and I have a table called `EDI_CUSTOMER` which has, as of now, only a few hundred records.

| customer | Code |
| --- | --- |
| AXEL | AA |
| AXEL | AB |
| Brian | BQ |
| Brian | BR |

A customer record can be repeated multiple times. I have to set a variable `@sendEDI = 'Y'` if a record exists for a particular customer. I am currently using this SQL.

```
SELECT @sendEDI = 'Y' 
FROM EDI_CUSTOMER 
WHERE customer = 'AXEL' 
GROUP BY customer
```

It works fine, but I am just curious if there are a million records for 'AXEL', then would it have any impact on performance?

I tried inserting 2 Million rows with around 1 million repeating rows for a customer. The SQL server does bring the result quite fast in about 150 milliseconds.

I tried using both `Group By` as my existing SQL and also using `EXISTS` as suggested. The performance is almost similar. The query plan shows that it still scans all the rows. Of course, creating the index on customer improves the performance a lot to around 1ms as it then does a seek.

Comment: Which database system are you using? Why not benchmark the query with some random data?

Comment: I am using Sql Server.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, what did your benchmark experiments return?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your SQL it seems like you are using the SQL Server.

You can use the `EXISTS` as `GROUP BY` will cause the extra cost to the the query and as you are just interested in the existence of the record, `EXISTS` will fit here.

You can create the `index` on `customer` column for better performance.

Use `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT @sendEDI = 'Y' 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EDI_CUSTOMER WHERE customer = 'AXEL')
```

Comment: Maybe, a `WITH (NOLOCK)` after `EDI_CUSTOMER` will be also useful.

Comment: `NOLOCK` can and will cause missing rows. (Also duplicate rows, but that is not relevant here)

Comment: @MuzafferGalata, see [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)